# How to use lambda with array Java

Tags: java, arrays, lambda

I have an Array

```
byte[] input = new byte[256];
```

I have map

```
Map<Byte, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>();
```

How can I put all elements in the order into lambda function?
I do like this, but is the other way to do it?

```
for (var b : input)
        frequencyMap.merge(b, 1, (o1, o2) -> o2 = frequencyMap.get(b) + 1);
```

How can I do this with out cycle?

Comment: HashMaps’s are unordered.

Comment: I need to put all array elements in the map. Using the word order, I meant by turns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's basically as good as it gets, except your merge function is overcomplicated.  Instead, write

```
frequencyMap.merge(b, 1, Integer::sum);
```

(or use a `Multiset` from `Guava`)

Comment: 'Integer::sum' it's some kind of magic! Im new in lambda, how does it understand, witch parameters I put into sum?

Comment: Well, `merge` assumes it's combining the value that's already in the map with the value you passed in...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required result using `groupingBy` and `summingInt` collectors.

```
Map<Byte, Integer> frequencyMap = 
       IntStream.range(0, input.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> input[i])
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
```

This means you don't need the external enhanced `for` loop iteration nor the `Map::merge`.